# Multiplying ascii code and getting string back

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption, split

I am trying to convert a string to ascii code and then multiplying that concatenation of the ascii codes by a number.

For example

```
String message = "Hello";
String result = "";
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
        temp = (int) message.charAt(i);
        result = result + String.value(temp).toString();
        arrayList.add(String.valueOf(temp).toString());
    }
```

I have tried two different ways, but there is always a catch with each one.

If I just concatenate all the ascii codes together into a string and I get `72101108108111` as my new string, the problem now is how can I get the original string back from this? This is because it is not obvious where each one character code starts and ends and the next one begins.

Another way I tried doing this was to use an array. I would receive `|72|101|108|108|111|` in an array. Obviously the codes are split here, but if I wanted to multiply this whole array (all the numbers as one number) by a number and then how would I get the array back together?

These are two different ways I have thought to solve this, but I have no idea how to get the string back out of these if I multiply the ascii by a number.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "multiply this whole array"? Can you give an example? Do you only have english words as strings, or any arbitrary characters? What are the different ways you've already considered for doing this, and what are the problems with them?

Comment: I would prefer not to use the array seeing I have to multiply the first one 72101108108111 by a number and will get that number back after an alogrithm.

Comment: I don't think your described transform is reversible (array to `BigInteger` is easy enough, and multiplication of the resulting `BigInteger` is easy, but then determining what digits mapped to in the original array doesn't appear obvious to me). How would you "uncarry" the digits?

Comment: So how would I go about recovering a concatenated ascii string ? Should I put it into binary?

Comment: Do you need ot use smallest possible representation of each code as string (7->"7", 32-> "32", 127-"127") or you can use longer (and hence reversible) representation like 5 characters for each (to fit whole char range) - 7 -> "00007", 127->"00127",...?

Comment: Doesn't matter but I will be multiplying the concatenated code exponentially so the number or string will get really really really big.

Comment: This question is quite confusing. Why don't you describe what you want to achieve. It seems you want to encrypt a string using a number (What number?) and then you want to decrypt it. Or are you asking how to get the characters back from the `|72|101|108|108|111|` arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the original string nor the ascii code string. Just have them both there, then whenever you need to get the numerical value of the string, just use `X.valueOf(...)`** method. Example,

```
final String message = "Hello";
final String result = "72101108108111";
long value = Long.valueOf(result);
```

If you do not want to store the two strings, then you should go with the array method. To get a numerical value, you simply concatenate all the strings in the array into one and use the `X.valueOf(..)` method.

And to get back the original string, use `Integer.valueOf(...)` on each string in the array, then cast each one to `char`.

```
System.out.println((char)Integer.valueOf("111").intValue());
```

** Note by X.valueOf(..), X doesn't have to be `Long` or `Integer` as I have shown. As you mentioned the value can get really large so `BigInteger` should be prefered above others

Comment: `X.valueOf`? These are going to be huge `BigInteger` numbers in general, well beyond the capacity of an `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: @Chris `X` can be any data type. BigInteger has the [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)) method as well, so it should still work